# playing music get stopped when call Share.open() in React native

Tags: react-native, react-native-sound, react-native-share

i have used latest version of
react-native-sound &
react-native-share

i have played audio using react-native-sound and on the similar page there is a share button, but when i press Share button and it open the share menu then my playing audio get stopped.
There is so many activity i have done, but no one activity produces stopping of the audio but only when user pressed share button and it just open the share popup audio will get stopped playing,
Please help someone, i have no idea regarding that what actually happen here and what to do for that.